# Make a selection

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I have to test an wysiwyg editor, using casperJS is great for this case bug I would like to test how things work on "selection".

How to say to casper "you have to select some text from here to here" ?

Thanks !

Comment: CasperJS doesn't have built-in function for this, but since it can run any javascript you can use [the answer or provided links from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11128130/1816580) inside the page context (inside `casper.evaluate`). The question is, why you would want to do this.

Comment: I would like to be able to select only a part of the text of the element. And another problem is that it should not be conscient of contained tags in order to simulate what any user can do. For example in the following text `<p>Hello i'm a guy <b>searching for a solution</b> with casper !<p>`, I could need to select the text from `guy` to `for`. The best solution would be to simulate a CTRL+F or something like that.

Comment: So you want it for screenshot purposes? Also, it seems from your description that you would know the text that you want to select beforehand.

Comment: Yes I know the text I want to select because it's for testing a WYSIWYG. So I define the text that should be select in order to test. I don't need to screenshot it.